# Stack Exchange community count mismatch

Tags: discussion, community

I see some mismatch with the Stack Exchange site counts.

In [Meta stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) page it shows "A list of all **151** Stack Exchange" sites

In [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com) page it shows "A list of all **153** Stack Exchange" sites

And in the Stack Exchange [Tour](https://stackexchange.com/tour) section it describes "Stack Exchange is a network of **150** communities that are created ... "

Is this a bug or cache? Or the shown communities are calculated in some other way?

Screenshot from Meta Stack Exchange:

> [image: Meta Stack Exchange]

Screenshot from Stack Exchange Tour page:

> [image: Stack Exchange Tour]

Comment: Lol, it's actually reported pretty often :)

Comment: @Shadow I see I was about 5 seconds too slow to get another helpful flag... ;)

Comment: @Nathan true, and a secret hat (that you already have on SO) here on MSE. ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Hadn't even looked that hat's requirements up yet, but heh.

Comment: Anyway, I don't think it's a bug anymore. It's showing the amount of sites you can actually see, e.g. if you search in the top bar under "more stack exchange communities", you can find private beta sites in there, and Area 51. However, those are not shown in the stackexchange.com sites list.