# Duplicate question plural issue in Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, duplicate-questions, plurals

I see a pluralization issue in my [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271749/312043) in the Stack Exchange Android app. But the same is correct in the web browsers.

**In Android app:**

[image: Android app]

**In web browsers:**

[image: Web browsers]

**Version:** Stack Exchange Android App Version 1.0.77

**Note:** Please don't add [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9694/312043) as a comment.

Comment: http://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105

> #Dear Next Person Who Opens a Pluralization 'Bug', I will personally come to your house and bludgeon you to death with a giant S

But not you. I like you. You're nice.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheTux: lol, I added in `Note`.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/utzTCyo.png

Comment: @TheGuywithTheTux: Yeah, I know that.

Comment: This also happens on the iOS app.