# The community count show differently

Tags: bug, communities-list

#### In SO, while hover over the drop down menu,

[image]

It shows there are **168** Communities

#### In SE main, when hover over the drop down menu,

[image]

It shows there are **170** communities

#### In the content of SE main,

[image]

It shows there are **167** communities

#### Actually there are 168 communities

[image]

Comment: @Arulkumar that is another one. Here it shows the number 170 but the site listed is 168. https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iBaO.png

Comment: If you are seeing the linked [duplicated questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271749/312043) that covered all the cases

Comment: @Arulkumar I am not only reporting the 2 different numbers in SE. both of them are wrong. One say 170 and one say 167. actually in the list, there are 168 sites.

Comment: There isn't "wrong" here, it all depends what sites exactly you include. e.g. Area 51 is not a Q&A site. stackexchange.com itself is not a Q&A site. So they are not counted in the sites count.

Comment: But site count is more than actual sites. There are actually 168 sites in the dropdown menu. But it shows 170